# Returning a simpler Iterator interface instead of a Map in Rust

Tags: rust

I'd like to write this:

```
fn fibs() -> std::iter::Iterator<int> {
    return std::iter::iterate((1i, 1i), |(a, b)| { (b, a + b) }).map(|(a, _)| a)
}
```

But if I do, I get this error:

```
error: explicit lifetime bound required
fn fibs() -> std::iter::Iterator<int> {
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If, instead I write out the full interface, it compiles:

```
fn fibs() -> std::iter::Map<'static, (int, int), int, std::iter::Iterate<'static, (int, int)>> {
    return std::iter::iterate((1i, 1i), |(a, b)| { (b, a + b) }).map(|(a, _)| a)
}
```

Is there a way to return the simpler interface?

Comment: Iterator is a trait and not a type. I don't know much about Rust but I think you need to pack it in Box. To return unboxed abstract types we need this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105

Answer (score 6):

There is not at present any way to return an abstract type such as `Iterator<T>`, just as you can’t assign that as the type of a variable (`let x: Iterator<uint>;` won’t compile for the same reasons).

This [has been discussed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105) and is certainly desired; when it is done it will probably be in the form `fn fibs() -> impl Iterator<uint>`, but you can’t do that yet.

Comment: It appears that the issue has been closed: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105. Is the RFC superseded by another one?

Comment: I don’t believe it has been for the moment, but it will be at some point.

Comment: Well, that’s not an RFC but rather a tracking issue for the concept which is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

as @ChrisMorgan said, for now you can't return an abstract type. If you are creating a public API and want to avoid depending too much on the specific implementation of `iterate` and `map`, you can encapsulate the return type into your own struct (which is more or less what the collections in the std library themselves do).

Something like:

```
// updated to rustc 0.13.0-nightly (2015-01-02) 
use std::iter::{Map, iterate, Unfold};

type Fibs = Map<(int, int), int, Unfold<(int, int), 
    (fn((int, int)) -> (int, int), Option<(int, int)>, bool), 
    fn(&mut (fn((int, int)) -> (int, int), Option<(int, int)>, bool)) -> 
        Option<(int, int)>>, fn((int, int)) -> int>;

struct Fibs2 {
    iter: Fibs,
}

impl Fibs2 {
    fn iter() -> Fibs2 {
        fn inner((a, b): (int, int)) -> (int, int) { (b, a + b) }
        let in_fn = inner as fn((int, int)) -> (int, int);

        fn first((a, _): (int, int)) -> int { a }
        let p_first = first as fn((int, int)) -> int;

        Fibs2{ iter: iterate((1i, 1i), in_fn).map(p_first) }
    }
}

impl Iterator<int> for Fibs2 {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<int> {
        self.iter.next()
    }
}

fn main() {
    for fib_n in Fibs2::iter().take(10) {
        println!("{}", fib_n);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think Swift does the same kind of thing but generically with AnySequence https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AnySequence_Structure/index.html