# How to create composite iterators with simple types

Tags: rust

Iterators in Rust are very convenient and powerful, and in particular they are designed to be easily composable, as in this example from the docs:

```
let iter = [1, 4, 2, 3].iter()
        .cloned()
        .inspect(|x| println!("about to filter: {}", x))
        .filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0)
        .inspect(|x| println!("made it through filter: {}", x));
```

There is a drawback, however. Note that `iter` here has no stated type. The reason is because the type is something horrible; if I try it I get the type:

```
iter: core::iter::Inspect<
        core::iter::Filter<
          core::iter::Inspect<
            core::iter::Cloned<core::slice::Iter<'a, usize>>,
            [closure@test.rs:...]>,
          [closure@test.rs:...]>,
        [closure@test.rs:...]>
```

In fact, because of the closure types I can't even type this in if I wanted to. (I could circumvent this problem by defining the functions with explicit names.) By comparison to Java, this seems overly complex, since it could just promote the types to `Iterator<T>` each time, but this is necessary for Rust's monomorphism + static dispatch to work.

Suppose I wanted to define this as an iterator adapter, that is:

```
fn adapter<'a, I: Sized + Iterator<Self=&'a usize>>(i: I) -> MyAdapter<'a, I> {
    i.cloned()
        .inspect(|x| println!("about to filter: {}", x))
        .filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0)
        .inspect(|x| println!("made it through filter: {}", x))
}
```

I don't want to expose to the clients of my code the details of the interior adapter chain, instead giving it the new name `MyAdapter<'a, I>`, but I also don't want to write my own `next()` method since I already have a perfectly good composite implementation. Is there a way to satisfy both these goals, and still have a static dispatch?

Comment: No. See a plethora of existing questions about this topic: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26329231/155423), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27646925/155423), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31904842/155423), and so on. You want the ["abstract return types" RFC](https://github.com/Kimundi/rfcs/blob/conservative-impl-trait-the/text/0000-conservative-impl-trait.md) (sometimes called "impl trait"). Please pick the most useful question and mark this as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, I was looking for the "newtype" and "type alias" methods in [1]. (Although the impl trait approach will also be nice when it lands.) Closing as dupe...