# How to return an Iterator from a Map

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function that returns a iterator of `PathBuf`s.

It tries to load a `.gitignore` file but if it can't find one just returns all files in the directory tree. I'm using the gitignore and glob crates for this.

```
fn get_files(){
    let pwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let gitignore_path = pwd.join(".gitignore");

    let files = match gitignore::File::new(&gitignore_path) {
        Err(_) => glob("**/*").expect("Failed to read glob pattern").map(|x| x.unwrap()),
        Ok(g)  => g.included_files().expect("Failed to read .gitignore").iter()
    };

    files.map(|p| pwd.join(p)).filter(|p| metadata(p).unwrap().is_file()) 
}
```

Since I'm mapping over the result of the glob, the inferred return type is `std::iter::Map` and `std::slice::Iter`. I understand that Map is an iterator adapter but how can I convert it to a type that implements `Iterator`?

Comment: `Map` _is_ already an iterator. You may find what you need in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/1233251).

Comment: `Map` implements `Iterator`.

Comment: Related questions: [Return a map iterator which is using a closure in Rust](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31904842/155423), [How do I return a Filter iterator from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27646925/155423), [Returning a simpler Iterator interface instead of a Map in Rust](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26329231/155423). **Please** do some basic searching before asking a question.